# Heatmap/Data visualization using WMS layer from Geoserver

Tags: plugins, heatmap, geoserver, wms, information-visualization

I want to find something that can be used to create heat map WMS layers from Geoserver. I found AcidMaps (http://acidmaps.org/) that can be used as a plugin to Geoserver to generate heatmap WMS layers. But I was wondering if anyone has some information about this.

Answer (score 3):

Server side heatmaps using Geoserver SLD

http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld-reference/rastersymbolizer.html#colormap

Also see Acidmaps which can be used as a Geoserver plugin
http://acidmaps.org/